# How to style text to not break word when break line?

Tags: react-native

[image: break word when break line]

```
txtLeft: {
    flex: 7,
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontFamily: theme.Font.Bold,
    color: theme.Color.Gray,
    paddingRight: 20,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },

  txtRight: {
    flex: 3,
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: theme.Color.Gray,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

set `textBreakStrategy` of your `Text` component to `simple`

```
<Text textBreakStrategy="simple">You text goes here</Text>
```

*available on Android API Level 23+*